Hooking backspace character
I have already found the proper hook for when the character is inserted(post-self-insert-hook), but how to hook when a character is deleted?
Also, how to get the character that was deleted, I am trying to make a similiar extension to smartparens and I need if the first paren is deleted to also delete the character in front of the cursor.

You can look at the source code of smartparens to learn how it handles the same requirement.

Tried searching for specifically hooks and didn't find it, thats why I asked. Didn't know advices even existed before :D

When you delete a character, a (delete-backward-char) is being called, and if you look at its sources, which are really short, you'll find out the function doesn't run any hooks.
So your functional has to be implemented with advices instead. For example, here's one to print the content that delete-backward-char is about to remove:
(defun my-advice-delete-backward-char (orig-func n &optional killflag)
  (let* ((start (max (point-min) (- (point) n)))
         (str (buffer-substring-no-properties start (point))))
    (print (concat "Removing chars: " str)))
  (funcall orig-func n killflag))

(advice-add #'delete-backward-char :around #'my-advice-delete-backward-char)

P.S.: depending on your purpose, you may want to advice a (delete-char) instead, which is the function being called by (delete-backward-char) with N being negative meaning "remove backwards". The difference is that there may be functions besides (delete-backward-char) that would do similar things, and the question is whether you want to have them advised as well.
An example might be dh in Evil "normal mode" which would remove character on the left. That said, I personally as an Evil user never use that combination just to remove a single character, and pressing Backspace in "insert mode" is bound to (delete-backward-char) anyway ‍♂️
